# i need make a count(*) of two elements of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, count

i have the following problem, in my database i have two tables:

tableA:

| Column A | Column B | Column c | Column d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/22 | add | 0 |
| 2 | 01/20 | del | 1 |
| 3 | 01/22 | add | 1 |
| 4 | 01/21 | del | 1 |
| 5 | 01/21 | add | 2 |
| 6 | 01/21 | del | 2 |

tableB:

| Column A | Column B | Column c | Column d | Column e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/22 | add | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 01/20 | del | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 01/22 | add | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 01/21 | del | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 01/21 | add | 2 | 0 |
| 6 | 01/21 | del | 2 | 1 |

now a need obtain the union to this tables to the next form:

```
Select count(a.Column a), count(b.Column e = 1) 1, count(b.Column e = 0) 0, column B 
From tableA a, tableB b where a.column d = b.column d group By a.column B;
```

some like this. I'm not sure to explain me

i need to pull apart the column e in two diferent and make the count.
to this form:

| count(a.Column a) | count(1) | count(0) | column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 01/20 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 01/21 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 01/22 |

Comment: Use conditional aggregation: `COUNT(CASE WHEN b.[Column e] = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Count_1, COUNT(CASE WHEN b.[Column e] = 0 THEN 1 END) AS Count_0`.  The CASE statements will either produce a value (1) or a NULL (the implicit ELSE default). `COUNT()` only counts the non-null values.  The other feature you can look into is a `PIVOT`.

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using the following:

```
sum(case when b.Column e = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 0,  
sum(case when b.Column e > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 1
```

```
select
    count(a.Column a), sum(case when b.Column e = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 0
    , sum(case when b.Column e > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 1,
column B
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.column d = b.column d
group by a.column B;
```

Comment: Best practice is to use proper explicit joins, not old-style comma-joins.

Comment: This will not produce such result, because join condition has duplicates in both tables

Comment: how you say that i can make this?